# React handle fetch API response in one place

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I'm trying to write one method for handling response from all of my fetch API's calls to deal with different scenarios:

```
async handleResponse(response, /*retrieveData=false,*/ isJson=false, isText=false , isBoolean=false) {
    if (response.ok) {
        // return await extractDataFromResponse(response, isJson, isText, isBoolean)
        // if (retrieveData) {
            if (isJson) {
                return await response.json().then((data) => {
                    return data; // Return json Data
                })
                // return response.json()
            } else if (isText) {
                return await response.text().then((data) => {
                    return data; // Return text Data
                })
                // return response.text()
            }
            else if (isBoolean) {
                return await response.text().then((data) => {
                    return data==="true"; // Return boolean Data
                })
            }
            else {
                return response // Return Http response object
            }
        // } else {
        //     return response // Return Http response object
        // }
    } else {
        return response.json() // Will include the error message (response.message)
    }
}
```

This method is in a base class, and it can be used from other class inheriting it as follow:

```
isProjectOpened(userSessionId="") {
    const url = new URL(webServicesBaseUrl + '/ProjectEditor/isProjectOpened'),
        params = {userSessionId: userSessionId}
    Object.keys(params).forEach(key => url.searchParams.append(key, params[key]))

    return fetch(url,
        {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: headers
        })
        // .then((response) => response.text())
        // .then((data) => {
        //     return data === "true";
        // })
        .then( (response) => {
            return this.handleResponse(response,false, false, true)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            raiseError(error)
        });
        // .catch(console.log);
}
```

The problem is with the blocks `isJson`, `isText`, `isBoolean` it return back to method that calls it before reaching the `return data` part.

How can I handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `then` chain to handle the result.

```
.then( (response) => {
            return this.handleResponse(response,false, false, true)
        })
        .then((data) => { console.log(data); })
        .catch((error) => {
            raiseError(error)
        });
```

Comment: Thanks. The order of execution is correct now and it's reaching "then" chain but data is undefined!

Comment: I had to add "return" before the await. (edited in my post)